# time series classification of an event either happening or not happening using machine learning techniques

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I have sensor data that I would like to use to classify whether an an event (giving birth) is about to occur within (2-4hrs) in an animal based on various metrics collected by the sensor(activity index, steps, time spent standing, time spent lying, number of times the animal lay down in the time block). The sensor data is collected in 15 minute blocks. I currently have about 50 animals in my study. I have done a bit of research on machine learning methods that might be suitable and have come up with:-

1. Convolutional Neural Networks
2. Recurrent Neural Networks
3. Hidden Markov Models
4. Least Squares SVMs

I am leaning towards either the convnet or recurrent neural net.

I have decided to use the python keras library running on theano to create and optimize my models(neural nets) as my environment is python based.

As I have limited time in which to get this done, I would like help/advice with the following:-

1. What neural net do you think would work best
2. How can I arrange my data for training (see data structure below)

|animal id|time stamp|activity index|steps|standing time|lying time|lying bout|birth|

animal id - string
time-stamp -datetime
activityindex - float
steps - int
standtime -float
lyingtime - float
lyingbout - int
birth - yes/no

time-stamps are in 15 min intervals but I would like to downsample to 1hr and 2hr blocks respectively and pass these as 2 separate data sets to my model.

Comment: I recommend you to study [tag:survival-analysis], basically the study of the expected time until an event happen. There are many neural networks coerced to do that too.